# Trouble with views on the stack

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I'm having trouble using a tab navigation application. Basically I start on this screen here

[image]

And when I click login, it will take me to this page on the same tab

[image]

However when I click logout, it takes me to the original screen which you see. BUT if I have logged out, and visit another tab, and then revisit the "profile tab" it is stuck in the second screen, and I can't even click logout anymore, it seems as if the view is stuck on the stack perhaps? I use this in my first view controller to access the second:

```
-(void)Bootup{

FourthViewController *home = [[FourthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FourthView" bundle:nil]; 
self.view = [home view];
```

}

and I use this in the second view controller

```
-(IBAction)switchPage:(id)sender
{
//[self someUpdateFunction];
FirstViewController *home = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstView" bundle:nil]; 
self.view = [home view]; 

}
```

Any ideas as to why I might be experiencing the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use for adding a view,

follow this code - [self.view addSubview:[controller view]];

And to remove  - [self.view removeFromSuperview];